# Libtiff install for Mac

Tags: r, libtiff

After updating to R 3.1.0, I attempted to install the rtiff package. I am getting the following error

```
    checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
    Try static libs needed on OS X
    checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
    Error: Could not find lib tiff.
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rtiff’
    * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rtiff’
```

This package worked in version 2.15.
I installed Libtiff with macports and this error persists.
I am working on Mac OSX Maveriks.
Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated

Comment: looks like this is an old problem - https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280216.html - though I have no trouble with the rtiff source package using the homebrew libtiff.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this link. Unfortunately I don't think it is recommended to use different 3rd party installers on the same system.

Comment: In fact it's recommended not to use _any_ third party installers for packages that R will be using. They don't install in the correct directory. This is the (external) tiff package provided at the att.research site: http://r.research.att.com/src/tiff-4.0.3.tar.gz . You may need to remove the current tiff installation.

Comment: I am now running R 3.0.0 GUI 1.60 Snow Leopard build (downgraded from 3.1.0) as this is the latest version that seems to be able to install rtiff on Maveriks.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  Installing libtiff via homebrew solved my problem. THX